# Error Webservice de la DIAN al Enviar Factura Electronic

Tags: php, webservice, soap

Con la pobre documentacion que existe respecto a la implementacion con el WebService ayer y hoy agote mis recursos para investigar el error que estoy recibiendo, y asumiendo que la misma DIAN (entidad Tributaria en Colombia) no responde los telefonos (estuve colgado 2 horas y nada...) y mucho menos los correos pues pongo aca la pregunta haber si alguien me puede ayudar y de igual manera le sirve a algun programador que ande en la misma situacion.

Al enviar la factura recibo un error que indica "**JBWEB000120: The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect**".

Les paso el Request y el Respose completo:

```
POST /habilitacion/B2BIntegrationEngine/FacturaElectronica HTTP/1.0
Host: facturaelectronica.dian.gov.co
User-Agent: NuSOAP/0.9.5 (1.123)
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Length: 28319
<soap-env:envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:rep="http://www.dian.gov.co/servicios/facturaelectronica/ReportarFactura" xmlns:ns2323="http://tempuri.org">
    <soap-env:header>
        <wsse:security soapenv:mustunderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:usernametoken wsu:id="UsernameToken-2">
                <wsse:username>d8xxx-exxx-4xxx-axxx-aaxxxx</wsse:username>
                <wsse:password type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile1.0#PasswordText">a8bxxxxHash265xxxxxx99</wsse:password>
                <wsse:nonce encodingtype="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security1.0#Base64Binary">bW9uxxxxxxxxxxxxxxUyNg==</wsse:nonce>
                <wsu:created>2019-01-23T16:08:39-06:00</wsu:created>
            </wsse:usernametoken>
        </wsse:security>
    </soap-env:header>
    <soap-env:body>
        <rep:enviofacturaelectronicapeticion>
            <rep:nit>700xxxx</rep:nit>
            <rep:invoicenumber>980000000</rep:invoicenumber>
            <rep:issuedate>2019-01-23T16:08:39-06:00</rep:issuedate>
            <rep:document>UEsDBBQA.....AuMS4yNzA3</rep:document>
        </rep:enviofacturaelectronicapeticion>
    </soap-env:body>
</soap-env:envelope>
```

Y el response:

```
<title>JBoss Web/7.4.8.Final-redhat-4 - JBWEB000064: Error report</title>
<h1>JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 400 - </h1>
<p><b>JBWEB000309: type</b> JBWEB000067: Status report</p>
<p><b>JBWEB000068: message</b> <u></u></p>
<p><b>JBWEB000069: description</b> <u>JBWEB000120: The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.</u></p>
```

---- Editado 2019/01/30, 15:38.
Le hice algunos cambios a la libreria NuSOAP ya que al mandar la informacion pasaba todo a minusculas (strtolower()), por lo cual quite el uso de la funcion strtolower() en todo lo que consistia *enviar*, y el error ahora cambio, me dice:

> HTTP/1.0 302 Found Location:
>   https://facturaelectronica.dian.gov.co/habilitacion/B2BIntegrationEngine/FacturaElectronica
>   Server: BigIP Connection: close Content-Length: 0

El problema persiste :(....

---- Editado 2019/01/31, 13:15.
Despues de probar con SOAPUI me percate que el problema principal son las librerias NuSOAP, asi que debido a tiempo que he perdido en esto y contemplando que me parece mas factible hacerme el codigo en Socket armando la trama para verificar si existen problemas con el WebService de la DIAN he optado por armarlo a mano.

Lo codifique y acabo de darme cuenta que por alguna razon que desconozco NuSOAP hace otras cosas que botan el error que se menciona al principio. Ahorita estoy hablando con la DIAN porque estoy enviando a mano la trama tal cual como la requiere el WebService y no deja de marcarme el error de:

> ClientThe security token could not be authenticated or authorized;
>   nested exception is org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: The
>   security token could not be authenticated or authorized

Y el codigo que tengo hasta ahorita para las pruebas a mano es:

```
<?php
public function createXML() {
        # crea el XML SOAP
    }

public funciton getXML() {
        # retorna el xml con $xml->saveXML();
    }

public function sendToDIAN($wsUrl) {
            $this->createXML();
            $s= curl_init();
            curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_URL, $wsUrl);
            curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("User-Agent: moneyBox", "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8", "SOAPAction:", "Content-Length: ". strlen($this->getXML())) );
            curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1 );
            curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->getXML());
            curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($s, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
            $resp= curl_exec($s);
            $rq= curl_getinfo($s);

            echo "<br>WS: ". $wsUrl;
            echo "<br>XML:<br>";
            print_r($this->getXML());
            echo "<br>Request:<br>";
            print_r($rq["request_header"]);
            echo "<br><br>Response:<br>";
            print_r($resp);
?>
```

El Request es:

```
POST /habilitacion/B2BIntegrationEngine/FacturaElectronica/facturaElectronica.wsdl HTTP/1.1
Host: facturaelectronica.dian.gov.co
Accept: */*
User-Agent: PHP
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 28198
Expect: 100-continue

<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
<soapenv:envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:rep="http://www.dian.gov.co/servicios/facturaelectronica/ReportarFactura">
    <soapenv:header>
        <wsse:security soapenv:mustunderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:usernametoken wsu:id="UsernameToken-2">
                <wsse:username>d8xxx-exxx-4xx0-axx2-aa4xxxxxda</wsse:username>
                <wsse:password type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile1.0#PasswordText">2fb7a2xxxxxxxxe6de4a</wsse:password>
                <wsse:nonce encodingtype="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security1.0#Base64Binary">bW9xxxxxMTU1MA==</wsse:nonce>
                <wsu:created>2019-01-31T14:05:50.000Z</wsu:created>
            </wsse:usernametoken>
        </wsse:security>
    </soapenv:header>
    <soapenv:body>
        <rep:enviofacturaelectronicapeticion>
            <rep:nit>700xxxx7</rep:nit>
            <rep:invoicenumber>980000000</rep:invoicenumber>
            <rep:issuedate>2019-01-31T14:05:50</rep:issuedate>
            <rep:document>UEsDBB....jEuMjcwNw==</rep:document>
        </rep:enviofacturaelectronicapeticion>
    </soapenv:body>
</soapenv:envelope>
```

El Response es:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Thu, 31 Jan 2019 19:05:51 GMT
Accept: text/xml, text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 443
X-Cnection: close
Set-Cookie: TS0133d910=01ca0e1ef6f0097a1348704194309a4e9b294fed9c0bcca644e4ae8558c221f7f76b430cee909654460964cd09e1ac5affe8cd8d04; Path=/

<soap-env:envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap-env:header></soap-env:header>
    <soap-env:body>
        <soap-env:fault>
            <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring xml:lang="en">The security token could not be authenticated or authorized; nested exception is org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: The security token could not be authenticated or authorized</faultstring>
        </soap-env:fault>
    </soap-env:body>
</soap-env:envelope>
```

Comment: No he llegado hasta ese punto, pero trata de cambiar el formato de la fecha.
En la cabecera <wsu:created>2019-01-23T16:08:39.000z</wsu:created> En el cuerpo <rep:issuedate>2019-01-23T16:08:39</rep:issuedate> Aunque la cabecera debería tener unos segundos o milisegundos mas que la fecha en que se creo la factura.

Comment: Ya he probado de todo, es desesperante porque hasta setie TODAS las etiquetas a 0 (cero) y sigue diciendo el mismo error. Es como si ni se preocupara por validar y simplemente en respuesta diera dicho error. Que por cierto segun el manual del estandar la fecha debe ir en formato: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS  unicamente

Comment: @moneyBox Yo estoy tratando de implementarlo pero con javascript (MEAN stack) pero no he llegado hasta ese punto, solo me causó curiosidad lo de la hora, he escuchado que la hora tanto de la factura, como de la firma, como el envió del soap deben ser distintas así sea por segundos y me pareció curioso que en el código que muestras es igual... ademas de que tiene el -06:00, aquí en Colombia es -05:00 pero no veo que haya que ponerlo... quizás en pocas horas/días te pueda colaborar mucho más.

Comment: Pues he probado cambiando ese detalle y continua indicandome lo mismo :(... Por otro lado, como te comente, el mismo manual indica que se requiere la hora en este formado: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS  unicamente.

Comment: Revisa que las credenciales para ese usuario estén activas en la DIAN. Suena a que esta inactivo y por eso no autentica

Comment: Hey @moneyBox , de casualidad puedes ayudarme con una guía para poder tener una idea mas fundamentada del como implementar esta solución. realmente hay poca información al respecto, además de que no es mi fuerte...

Comment: @jecorrales la info esta en el portal de la DIAN, checa los Anexos Tecnicos.

Comment: @Alfabravo si esta activa la cuenta mire: https://i.imgur.com/lye4byQ.jpg
Verifique tambien los datos, que la CLAVE asignada a fuera la correcta.

Comment: @Alfabravo Listo ya lo soluciones :D.... algo pasaba con ese ID de software, que cree uno nuevo y con este si me dejo pasar :D

Comment: Revertí tu edición, la respuesta va en la zona de respuestas y no en la pregunta, escríbele, explícala y te la calificamos

Comment: @element me marca un error al quere poner mi respuesta, no me permite hacerlo :(

Comment: @element no me deja poner respuesta, tengo algun tipo de **restriccion**

Comment: sería interesante que describas el error exacto que te muestra, que aparece?

Comment: @element te dejo screenshot del recuadro con fondo rojo pastel: https://i.imgur.com/RYpX98J.png , al final simplemente no me deja publicar la respuesta... Ni en esta ni ninguna publicacion.

Comment: entiendo, esto es relacionado a que varios de tus aportes no han sido bien recibidos y han tenido varias votaciones negativas de manera continua, por eso el sistema te muestra eso, trata de evitar en el futuro respuestas que no sigan [answer] y preguntas que no sigan [ask] para evitar esta situación

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Después de varias ediciones de la publicación inicial finalmente la solución fue que para efectos de cumplir los requerimientos de la entidad Tributaria DIAN para el armado del Request SOAP "taaan personalizada" opte por no usar la librería NuSOAP ni tampoco SOAPClient(), ya que cualquier valor distinto o adicional que se anexara a las etiquetas me estaba tirando mensajes de error sin descripción especifica para su resolución y la inversión de tiempo en el debuggeo y solución me estaba retrasando por mucho, por lo cual tuve que armar el XML del Request de forma "manual" usando **DOMDocument** y realizando la conexión por Socket (cURL).

Otro tip adicional que es **IMPORTANTE MENCIONAR** es que, después de realizar la conexión SOAP "a mano", el error fue mas "accesible" ya que mencionaba "Error en la autentificacion", y para este caso en particular después de agotar las opciones de: Verificar que el ID Software, la Url SOAP y el Password estuvieran correctas, tuve que optar por **eliminar el Software ID** del portal de la DIAN y volverlo a generar, esto soluciono la parte de **Error de la autenticacion**. Posiblemente fue por cambios en el sistema de la DIAN que afecta a los Software ID en **modo Prueba**, pero esa fue la 2da solución.

Aquí una idea del código que genere finalmente para la parte manual:

```
<?php
private $xml=NULL;

public function createXML() {
    /*
    creamos el XML con DOMDocument() cone tiquetas <soapenv:Envolve>........</soapenv:Envolve> y los guardamos al final
    */
}

public function getXML() {
    return $this->xml->saveXML();
}

public function sendToDian($wsUrl) {
    $this->createXML();
    $s= curl_init();
    curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_URL, $wsUrl);
    curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("User-Agent: PHP", "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8", "SOAPAction:", "Content-Length: ". strlen($this->getXML())) );
    curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1 );
    curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->getXML());
    curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($s, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    $resp= curl_exec($s);
    $rq= curl_getinfo($s);

    echo "<br>XML:<br>";
    print_r($this->getXML());
    echo "<br>Request:<br>";
    print_r($rq["request_header"]);
}
?>
```

El Request:

```
POST /habilitacion/B2BIntegrationEngine/FacturaElectronica/facturaElectronica.wsdl HTTP/1.1
Host: facturaelectronica.dian.gov.co
Accept: */*
User-Agent: PHP
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 28198
Expect: 100-continue

<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
<soapenv:envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:rep="http://www.dian.gov.co/servicios/facturaelectronica/ReportarFactura">
    <soapenv:header>
        <wsse:security soapenv:mustunderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:usernametoken wsu:id="UsernameToken-2">
                <wsse:username>d8xxx-exxx-4xx0-axx2-aa4xxxxxda</wsse:username>
                <wsse:password type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile1.0#PasswordText">2fb7a2xxxxxxxxe6de4a</wsse:password>
                <wsse:nonce encodingtype="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security1.0#Base64Binary">bW9xxxxxMTU1MA==</wsse:nonce>
                <wsu:created>2019-01-31T14:05:50.000Z</wsu:created>
            </wsse:usernametoken>
        </wsse:security>
    </soapenv:header>
    <soapenv:body>
        <rep:enviofacturaelectronicapeticion>
            <rep:nit>700xxxx7</rep:nit>
            <rep:invoicenumber>980000000</rep:invoicenumber>
            <rep:issuedate>2019-01-31T14:05:50</rep:issuedate>
            <rep:document>UEsDBB....jEuMjcwNw==</rep:document>
        </rep:enviofacturaelectronicapeticion>
    </soapenv:body>
</soapenv:envelope>
```

> **Consideraciones:** debes mandar la etiqueta  tal cual y excatamente lo pide la DIAN, por ejemplo algunas aplicaciones crean
>   los "Namespace" asi: "ns1:URL", y la DIAN te lo va rechazar, debe ser
>   exactamente como te lo piden. De igual forma los atributos de cada
>   etiqueta muchos diran "pues menciono la URL en el Nodo Principal",
>   pues NO, debes mencionar la URL dentro de los argumentos donde
>   especificamente los quiere leer la DIAN.